# Regex - non-capturing condition in larger capture

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out this regex. I have a series of lines:

```
cola String(18,2), nullable=False, default='N'
colb Decimal(18,2), nullable=False, default=0
colc String(18), nullable=False, default='TAA'
cold Integer, nullable=False, default=1
```

Now, I'm trying to break it into this:

```
cola || String(18,2) || , nullable=False, default='N'
colb || Decimal(18,2) || , nullable=False, default=0
colc || String(18) || , nullable=False, default='TAA'
cold || Integer || , nullable=False, default=1
```

I've written a regex which gets someway there:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}) ([a-zA-Z]{1,}(?:\([0-9,]{1,7}[0-9]{0,}\))|(?:,))(.*)
```

this returns:

```
cola || String(18,2) || , nullable=False, default='N'
colb || Decimal(18,2) || , nullable=False, default=0
colc || String(18) || , nullable=False, default='TAA'
cold Integer, nullable=False, default=1
```

Notice, the last line is not replaced. Here is the replace requirement:

```
\1 || \2 || \3
```

So, my thinking was, if I put a conditional non-capturing check inside the second capture it would find the first piece (the column type), then check for a (xxx,yyy) value after it, if it didn't exist, it was still valid to return \2 as the column type.

Clearly, I've made massive assumptions about this function, but I can't seem to find the right explanations on the net that make sense to me, in a way that I can fix this regex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

** FIXED ** I forgot to make it "optional" :/

([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}) ([a-zA-Z]{1,}(?:([0-9,]{1,7}[0-9]{0,}))?)(.*)

Comment: Found the issue! Only after I wrote this question was it obvious... I'm forgetting to make it optional! ([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}) ([a-zA-Z]{1,}(?:\([0-9,]{1,7}[0-9]{0,}\))?)(.*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are so close!

Change

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}) ([a-zA-Z]{1,}(?:\([0-9,]{1,7}[0-9]{0,}\))|(?:,))(.*)
```

to

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,}) ([a-zA-Z]{1,}(?:\([0-9,]{1,7}[0-9]{0,}\))?|(?:,))(.*)
```

Comment: yeah just figured that out! :)

Comment: Sweet! I'll pretend I helped  ;)

Comment: You know... If you accepted my answer... You'd push me over the 1000 mark...  I'll be your best friend...

Comment: I was going to anyway as it is the correct answer - but won't let me for another 5 minutes...

Comment: Awesome!! Glad you figured it out, and thanks for the final push to this milestone.

Comment: :D   Man I love stackoverflow.